# "NotAvailable" and "NotApplicable" data points returned by WeatherData[]

Tags: plotting, data, vector, curated-data

I am trying to use `ListVectorPlot` in combination with `WeatherData` and `CountryData` to show wind velocity vectors over a given country. The problem I am having stems from "NotAvailable" and "NotApplicable" data from a function in which the wind's velocity vector is constructed. The function is

```
WindFoo[x_, y_] := -WeatherData[{y, x}, "WindSpeed"] {1/Cos[y °], 
   1} Through[{Sin, Cos}[WeatherData[{y, x}, "WindDirection"] °]]
```

Note: I am not able to display the degree symbol, so it is written out in the above code.

How can the code above be modified to exclude the cases of "NotAvailable" and "NotApplicable" data to work in manner similar to the wind velocity vectors shown over Australia in the following tutorial: http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/01/13/visualizing-weather-patterns-in-mathematica-7/

Comment: what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @ubpdqn version 10

Comment: `GeoGraphics` in version 10 can be used for map but requires some work to get the vector plot as you cannot combine with `Show`. However, you can use `CountryData["Australia","Schematic Polygon"]`. With respect to the removal of missing data, there are two issues. In v 10 the above produces things with units so need to strip `QuantityMagnitude` and probably easier to do `Cases` where data all numeric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This uses some version 10 functions:

Getting the data (takes time as I could have set this up better):

```
dat = Table[{i, j, 
    WeatherData[{j, i}, #] & /@ {"WindSpeed", "WindDirection"}}, {i, 
    113, 153, 4}, {j, -43, -11, 4}];
```

Processing:

```
data = Cases[{{#1, #2}, -QuantityMagnitude[#3[[1]]] {1/Cos[#2 Degree], 
        1} Through[{Sin, Cos}[#3[[2]]]]} & @@@ 
    Flatten[dat, 1], {_, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}}];
```

Visualizing:

```
ls = ListStreamPlot[data];
arrows = Cases[ls, Arrow[_], Infinity];
GeoGraphics[{Purple, arrows}]
```

[image]

Please look at documentation as must reverse coordinates if you choose to use `GeoPosition`. Obviously can modify to suit stylistic preferences and other needs.

**UPDATE**

Just to 'check' this with another source (noting I am not sure what `WeatherData` uses as default, I just assumed it used the most recent data): From [http://www.windfinder.com/weather-maps/forecast/australia#4/-24.69/\
135.79](http://www.windfinder.com/weather-maps/forecast/australia#4/-24.69/%5C%20135.79)
[image]

or a little before:

[image]

These seem somewhat similar to the Mathematica generated map.

Exploiting the hard work of **Gleno** and appropriately adapting code from the documentation of `WindVectorData` I believe yields the "correct" wind stream plot consistent with the check above (the issue is transforming the wind velocity components):

```
windVelocity[
  coords_] := {Reverse@
   coords, -Reverse@QuantityMagnitude[WindVectorData[coords]] {1/
     Cos[coords[[1]] \[Degree]], 1}}

wvd[country_String, date_, n_] := 
  Module[{box, latmin, latmax, longmin, longmax, pts, sample, stream, 
    latstep, longstep, ls, arrows}, 
   box = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ 
     Transpose@
      Cases[CountryData[country, "Polygon"], {_Real, _}, Infinity];
   {{latmin, latmax}, {longmin, longmax}} = box + {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}};
   latstep = (latmax - latmin)/(n - 1);
   longstep = (longmax - longmin)/(n - 1);
   pts = Flatten[
     Table[{lat, long}, {lat, latmin, latmax, latstep}, {long, 
       longmin, longmax, longstep}], 1];
   sample = windVelocity /@ pts;
   stream = Cases[sample, u_ /; FreeQ[u, "NotAvailable"]];
   ls = ListStreamPlot[stream];
   arrows = Cases[ls, Arrow[_], Infinity];
   GeoGraphics[arrows, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]
   ];
```

This leads to:

```
gr = wvd["Australia", Today, 10]
```

[image]

I guess *the answer my friend is blowing in the wind...*

Comment: The new maps in Mathematica 10 look really cool. I think at least one of us botched something, because we get quite stark disagreement on wind direction. I'll check tomorrow where the wind *actually* blows. ;)

Comment: @Gleno its probably me. I am just checking. Very much like yuor answer. Gets my vote.

Comment: @Gleno see my update...I think I have resolve this issue

Comment: Ah, well done sir!

Comment: I don't think I ever congratulated you on reaching 10K "reputation."  Nice job! It's been fun watching the quality of your answers improve over time.  I like to think I played some role in that. :-)  I know how long it takes to write 425 answers; thanks for giving back to the community!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. I have learned very much from you and the creative members of this community and look forward to learning more and more

Answer (score 11):

**NB** *I think there's a problem with this code, please see [this answer by ubpdqn](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55951/1657) for more information. I'll update these snippets when I get the chance.*

Yours is a question with many possible interpretations. I've chosen the interpretation that was most fun for me to play with, so...

```
ang = 20; (* divide the world into chunks of this size *)
pts = Flatten[Table[{lat, long}, {lat, -80, 80, ang}, {long, -180, 180, ang}], 1];
sample = WindVectorData[Replace[pts, c_ :> {c, Today}, 1]]; (* this takes forever *)

stream = Cases[Transpose@{Reverse/@pts, sample}, {_, Except[_Missing]}] /. 
    Quantity[v_, _] :> v /. Interval[lst_] :> Mean /@ lst;

(* This function crashes kernel very often, but in interpolation, I assume *)
streamplot = ListStreamPlot[stream, StreamColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
   InterpolationOrder -> None, StreamPoints -> Fine];

mpoly[poly_] := poly /. GeoPosition[pts_] :> pts 
                     /. {lat_Real, long_} :> {long, lat} 
                     /. Polygon[data_] :> Style[Polygon[data], Antialiasing -> True];

world = Graphics[{RGBColor[0.38, 0.77, 1.]}~Join~
    Table[mpoly@CountryData[c, "SchematicPolygon"], {c, CountryData[]}]];
g = Show[world, streamplot, ImageSize -> 1400]
```

If you have Mathematica 10, the graph `g` should be:

[image: Worlwinds]

Puting it together, you can have a function like

```
PlotWindBox[country_String, date_, n_] := 
  Module[{box, latmin, latmax, longmin, longmax, pts, sample, stream, 
    streamplot, mpoly, target, world, latstep, longstep},

   box = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ 
     Transpose@
      Cases[CountryData[country, "Polygon"], {_Real, _}, Infinity];
   {{latmin, latmax}, {longmin, longmax}} = box + {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}};


   latstep = (latmax - latmin)/(n - 1);
   longstep = (longmax - longmin)/(n - 1);
   pts = Flatten[
     Table[{lat, long}, {lat, latmin, latmax, latstep}, {long, 
       longmin, longmax, longstep}], 1];

   sample = WindVectorData[Replace[pts, c_ :> {c, date}, 1]];
   stream = 
    Cases[Transpose@{Reverse /@ pts, sample}, {_, 
        Except[_Missing]}] /. Quantity[v_, _] :> v /. 
     Interval[lst_] :> Mean /@ lst;
   streamplot = 
    ListStreamPlot[stream, StreamColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
     StreamPoints -> Fine, InterpolationOrder -> None];
   mpoly[poly_] := 
    poly /. 
       GeoPosition[pts_] :> pts /. {lat_Real, long_} :> {long, 
        lat} /. Polygon[data_] :> 
      Style[Polygon[data], Antialiasing -> True];
   target = 
    Graphics[{RGBColor[0.38, 0.77, 1.], 
      mpoly@CountryData[country, "Polygon"]}];
   world = 
    Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.84]}~Join~
      Table[mpoly@CountryData[c, "Polygon"], {c, 
        Cases[CountryData[], Except[Entity["Country", country]]]}]];
   Show[world, target, streamplot, ImageSize -> 1400, 
    PlotRange -> {{longmin, longmax}, {latmin, latmax}}]
   ];
```

Call it with `PlotWindBox["Australia", Today, 10]` (10 means that there are 10^2 sample points, try with fewer sample points if you are impatient like me) and obtain:

[image: Australia Weather]

Answer (score 6):

I feel a bit foolish posting such a simple answer after the two complete examples above, but I think it bears pointing out that version 10 includes a function specifically for removing [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Missing.html) values:

[`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteMissing.html):

[image]

Comment: version 10 keeps coming up with surprises some nice, like this one...very handy so thanks...many I am still adjusting to