# How to delete Missing["NotAvailable"] from list of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Considering we have a list of rules:

```
{ First-> {a-> "aaaa", b-> "bbbb"}, Second-> {c-> "cccc", d-> "dddd", e-> Missing["NotAvailable"], f-> Missing["NotAvailable"] }}
```

How can I bring this to be:

```
{ First-> {a-> "aaaa", b-> "bbbb"}, Second-> {c-> "cccc", d-> "dddd" }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(1234)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1234/121), [(40169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40169/121), [(55942)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55942/121), [(65923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65923/121).  Related: [(2655)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2655/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list =
 {First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd"e -> Missing["NotAvailable"], f -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}}

DeleteCases[list, Rule[_, _Missing], Infinity]
```

{First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, 
 Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd"}}

Answer (score 6):

you can use `DeleteMissing` also

```
l = {First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, 
  Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd", e -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
    f -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}};

Normal@DeleteMissing[Association@l, Infinity]
(*{First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"},Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd"}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative using `UpValues`:

```
Block[{Missing},
 Missing /: _ -> Missing["NotAvailable"] := Sequence[];
 {First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, 
  Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd", e -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
    f -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}}
 ]
(*
  {First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd"}}
*)
```

Comment: [That looks familiar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1235/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard really? I never would have guessed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Truthfully, I'm enamored with mma's [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and I think it should be demonstrated at every opportunity.

Comment: It *is* nice but [beware of packed arrays.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard packed arrays can be _special_, along with most things that are `AtomQ`.

Answer (score 3):

Less elegant than DeleteCases, however an alternative:

```
exp = {First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, 
  Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd", e -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
    f -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}}

 Delete[exp, Position[exp, _ -> _Missing]]
```

Or

```
 Delete[exp, Drop[#, -1] & /@ Position[exp, _Missing]]

(*{First -> {a -> "aaaa", b -> "bbbb"}, Second -> {c -> "cccc", d -> "dddd"}}*)
```